# How do I fix "failure in sending email Exception" in sending email in C#?

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient, mailing

I'm trying to send email (SMTP) with C#, but there is an exception, "failure sending email".

I enabled SSL in code and use 465 port (it's open) to send my email to Yahoo (smtp.mail.yahoo.com) with the system.net.mail library.

```cs
try
{
    string mass = " Hi, this is a compo team email to you for a verification code! Your verification code is: ''" + result + "'' You can enter this code to your compex for go ahead!!!";

    string frommail = "<my mail is here>";
    string tomail = emailtxt.Text;
    string submail = "verification";
    string smtptext = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
    string passmail = "<my email password here> ";
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(frommail, tomail, submail, mass);
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(smtptext);
    client.Port = 465;
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(frommail, passmail);
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.Send(mail);
    MessageBox.Show("email sent", "log", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    /////email
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
}
```

How can I fix it? What's wrong?

Comment: What is the full exception message?

Comment: just failure sending mail

Comment: You might want to try port 587 instead.

Comment: tried .no change "failure sending mail"again @john

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can do is checking if you can access Yahoo SMTP from your machine.

The easiest way to do it, is with Telnet.

Open a cmd window and run `telnet smtp.mail.yahoo.com 465`

With the answer you will be able to find if it is a problem of the firewall, security, or something else.

Comment: On what version of Windows did you try this? On Windows 10 you will get *"'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."*

Comment: Can you add [instructions on how to enable it](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/38433.windows-10-enabling-telnet-client.aspx)? There is likely a post here on Stack Exchange about it (e.g. [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour)).

Comment: [Possible command-line way of enabling it](https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-enable-the-telnet-client-in-windows-10/), `dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient`. But do test that it actually works.